# Electron titlebar interferes with mouse events

Tags: electron, titlebar

I have customized my Electron app's titlebar to be hidden but still display the traffic lights. In it's place I have created a custom titlebar which is `45` pixels high and contains several interactive elements, mainly buttons. This is my `BrowserWindow` configuration:

```js
{
    width: 2200,
    height: 1200,
    webPreferences:
    {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        preload: path.join(__dirname, './preload.js'),
    },
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    frame: false,
    titleBarOverlay: { height: 0 },
    titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
    trafficLightPosition: {x: 10, y:10},
    show: false,
}
```

The buttons I have added to the titlebar are about `32` pixels high and have the `cursor: pointer;` style along with a background that changes from **gray** to **white**. Whenever I hover over them, the background color correctly changes from gray to white, **however**, the cursor only changes to a pointer when I place my house on the bottom half of the button. It does not change to a point when my mouse is at the top half. The exact same thing happens whenever I hover selectable text, my pointer only changes on the bottom half of the element.

In the screenshot seen below, the red area is where my pointer does **not** change, and the blue area is where my pointer correctly changes.

[image: Visual explanation]

This bug does not happen when I hover over the button on the local server I use for Svelte, which is an address I can open in a web browser, meaning my CSS styling is not the issue.

Furthermore, when I don't hide the titlebar, or when set the `titleBarStyle` to `default`, the hover effects work just fine.

Based on the size of the button that doesn't work, I believe the titlebar could be "hidden" only visually and still be registering mouse events before my elements.

How can I track down what is causing this weird behavior?
Thank you for all the help.

Also, I am on macOS.